# Only Questionmarks in Linux dirlisting

Tags: linux, terminal

i'm doing a dir listing in my .ssh home dir which gives me a strange result:

```
ls -lsa .ssh/
total 0
? ?--------- ? ? ? ?            ? . ·
? ?--------- ? ? ? ?            ? .. ·
? ?--------- ? ? ? ?            ? authorized_keys ·
```

The weird thing is, that this only happens for one user and only in this specific directory. If I do the ls after a su -l, everything works as expected.  Another strange thing is, that my xterm shows the dir listing in a red blinking font!
Any ideas what's causing this to happen?

thx!

**Edit:**
Here is the dir listing as root:

```
ls -lsa
total 52
4 drw-------  2 sdd sdd 4096 Feb 10 15:57 .
4 drwx------ 16 sdd sdd 4096 Feb 10 15:57 ..
4 -rw-------  1 sdd sdd 1628 Feb 10 15:57 authorized_keys
```

I'm using ext3.

**Edit2:**
Thx for the answers, but i still get this:

```
chmod -R 600 /home/sdd/.ssh
ls -lsan _ssh.old/
total 0
? ?--------- ? ? ? ?            ? .
? ?--------- ? ? ? ?            ? ..
? ?--------- ? ? ? ?            ? authorized_keys
```

Comment: Can you post the output of ls -lah once root .. and tell us what file system you are using?

Comment: Does this user have a weird locale or weird terminal font?

Comment: no it's a "normal" font, i.e. no UTF8 stuff or anything

Comment: Could you update edit2? It doesn't make any sense, you're chmodding with the wrong mode (no execute) and then listing a different dir...

Answer (score 101, accepted):

That happens when the user can't do a stat() on the files (which requires execute permissions), but can read the directory entries (which requires read access on the directory).  So you get a list of files in the directory, but can't get any information on the files because they can't be read. :)  If you have a directory which has read permission but not execute, you'll see this.  Someone probably tried to protect the .ssh directory incorrectly - it should be "chmod 0700 .ssh/" and owned by the user which owns the homedir.  More than likely, someone was following instructions for securing a .ssh *file* but applied it to a .ssh directory. :)

If you do a chmod 0600 or 0400 on any directory, you can easily reproduce this behavior.  Add execute permission to the dir, and it'll work fine.

Comment: This solution didn't work for us since event the root user couldn't operate on the file.  Any suggestions?


[root@lxxxxx1 teamsite]# chmod 0777 private

chmod: cannot access `private': No such file or directory

[root@lxxxxxx1 teamsite]# chmod -R 0777 private

chmod: cannot access `private': No such file or directory

Comment: Troy - that trailing single quote is odd, indicating to me that you may have some kind of odd filename on the filesystem or a different problem from this one.  Ask a separate question about that, please.

Comment: Even in 2015 this is still a very useful answer. Thanks.

Comment: This will also happen if you have mounted a filesystem improperly. You can see the directory is there, but cannot stat it or delete it, even as root. First umount, then delete if necessary.